# If I try to print ch[0] or any random char of sorted char array after using Arrays.sort() it gives a blank output and thus the output is blank why?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, output

```
   class Solution
{
    public static String caseSort(String str)
    {
       char ch[]=new char[str.length()];
       char chy[]=new char[str.length()];
       int k=0,l=0;
       
       for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
       {
           if(str.charAt(i)>='a'&& str.charAt(i)<='z')
           ch[k++]=str.charAt(i);
         
           else
           chy[l++]=str.charAt(i);
       }
       Arrays.sort(ch);
       Arrays.sort(chy);
       
       int p=0,q=0; String stri="";
       for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
       {
          if(str.charAt(i)>='a'&& str.charAt(i)<='z')
          stri=stri+ch[p++];
        
          else
          stri=stri+chy[q++];
       }
       return stri;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please add a question, or at least some explanation to accompany your code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before sorting `ch` and `chy` arrays it is needed to trim them to remove empty cells with `'\0'` characters, for example, using method `Arrays::copyOf`:

```java
ch  = Arrays.copyOf(ch,  k);
chy = Arrays.copyOf(chy, l);
       
Arrays.sort(ch);
Arrays.sort(chy);
```

Or, `p` and `q` should be initialized with a certain shift instead of `0` - if `ch` contains `k` lower case letters, then `int p = ch.length - k;` and `q = chy.length - l;`

Also, it would be much better to use `StringBuilder` to concatenate the characters in the loop.

```java
int p = ch.length - k, q = chy.length - l; 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.length());

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) >= 'a' && str.charAt(i) <= 'z')
        sb.append(ch[p++]);
    else
        sb.append(chy[q++]);
}
return sb.toString();
```

Full code with more refactoring and test:

```java
public static String caseSort(String str) {
    if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
        return str;
    }
    
    int n = str.length();
    
    char ch[]  = new char[n];
    char chy[] = new char[n];
    int k = 0, l = 0;
       
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (c >= 'a' && c <='z')
            ch [k++] = c;
        else
            chy[l++] = c;
    }
//  ch  = Arrays.copyOf(ch,  k);
//  chy = Arrays.copyOf(chy, l);
       
    Arrays.sort(ch);
    Arrays.sort(chy);

    int p = ch.length - k, q = chy.length - l; 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n);

    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        sb.append(c >= 'a' && c <='z' ? ch[p++] : chy[q++]);
    }
    
    return sb.toString();
}

//  Test
System.out.println(caseSort("Hello,World!"));
```

Output:

```
!dell,HloorW
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is fine. The problem that is occurring is that you have defined your arrays with a length of the string so when you loop through and add characters in ch and chy arrays some places may be empty and when you sort this array those initial spaces will be at the start of the array and thus ch[0] will give a blank space.

Comment: there are no spaces in the String when I print it as a whole it prints properly just specific index characters are not getting printed